# Curve Modifier for making a pattern doesnt work

Tags: modeling

As you can see from the images, both origins are at the center, I applied the scale/rotation, scaled the circle or the pattern but it still doesnt work for some reason. Any help would be appreciated. Also other deformation axes doesnt work either.

For some reason Blend-Exchange is stuck, and I cant get it to work. So unfortunately I cant provide the .blend file.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's your desired result? A cylinder? A disc with a hole in it? Something else?

Comment: Plz attach your file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for detail answer

Comment: Yes, a cylinder with a hole in it. Think about it like a sheathe. For more information, check out this video, its basically what I'm trying to do. Unfortunately, the same things happened in this video doesnt happen to me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CxftwcyA7cA&t=238s

Also, @atek, it doesnt work. It's stuck at proccesing state. I'll leave it at this state for 1 hour, I hope it works